# How can I send a custom event to the client browser using Power Virtual Agents?

Tags: power-virtual-agents

I am building a bot with Power Virtual Agents and integrating it on my website. The customer can create support tickets through the bot using a Flow. I have a requirement to update my web page after the ticket is created to refresh the list of tickets on the page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new [Adaptive Dialog in Bot Framework Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-bot-framework-composer) to send an Event Activity to the client. Specifically:

1. Click the "Open in Bot Framework" button on the topic list page, open the bot in composer.
2. To transfer state from the bot to the client, you must make the applicable variables scoped to the entire Bot in Power Virtual Agents. In the topic that creates the ticket, make sure to mark the `ticketId` variable a global variable.
3. Create a new Dialog in the bot. In the `BeginDialog` trigger, add a `Send a response` node that contains the structured event payload:

```
[EventActivity
    name = OnTicketCreated
    value = ${virtualagent.ticketId}
]
```

4. Publish the changes in Composer to Power Virtual Agents.
5. At the end of the topic that creates the ticket, add a `Go to another topic` node and route the bot to the newly created dialog.
6. On the client side, handle the event using the `WebChat.createStore()` function. [Here is sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/c.incoming-activity-event).